# Share SessionManager between two WAR's on same tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8, shiro

**Problem:**

We have apache shiro authentication in our two applications, let's name them application1 (context is "/") and application2 (context is "/app2"). For basic authentication, it's working fine. We deploy these two applications on two tomcats (both applications on each tomcat) and then handle context sharing via tomcat 8 context sharing and for preserving sessions, we use memcached so that even if one tomcat is down, application and sessions remain preserved.

**How session is already handled?**

If user logs in on any of the two applications, their session is shared between two applications with getting the root context ("/") and then an interceptor to intercept any request and find if user is already logged in or not.

**New Requirement:**

Recently, we had to implement a functionality where we need to expire a certain user's all sessions on the basis of a certain trigger and I was reading about Apache Shiro's Session Management. I integrated in application1 and everything worked fine but now session sharing between application1 and application2 is gone.

I explained above scenario so that I could get right directions what exactly I should look for or try.

**What I want to do is**:

I want to somehow share shiro session manager between these two applications so that once it's shared, we can easily handle the session sharing part and rest of the functionality (invalidating sessions of some user) is already in place.

**Question:**

So, please tell me, if what I want to do is exactly what I should do and what I need to understand and read? OR if I am thinking in the wrong direction, please suggest me the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the book "**Pairing Apache Shiro and Java EE 7**" which you can grab for free [here](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/apache-shiro-ee-7).

[image]

The Session clustering feature can be done using the CacheManager. Shiro is natively supporting EhCache & Hazelcast. I recommend you to use Hazelcast.

Here is a sample project on github: [shiro-hazelcast-web-sample](https://github.com/stormpath/shiro-hazelcast-web-sample)

To go deep in Hazelcast features, you can override Shiro's CacheManager, and implement what do you want of Hazelcast features:

- [Web Session Clustering](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/web-session-clustering/)
- [Generic Web Session Replication](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/web-session-clustering/generic-web-session-replication/)
- [Tomcat Web Session Replication](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/web-session-clustering/tomcat-web-session-replication/)